# Python Dictionarys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am stucked with a school project. The following function should set the name of a room in a given dictionary.The rooms dicionary should stay because functions using it.It should randomly set the name of the rom to display it later in another function.

```
import string
import random

names = ['This', 'happens', 'all', 'the', 'time']
for key, value in rooms.items():
    # do something with value
    rooms[value]["name"] = random.choice(names)
    names.remove(rooms[value]["name"])

room_1 = {"name" : "",
          "description" : """ """,
          "exits" : {"east": "Second" , "south":"Fourth"},
          "items" : []}

room_2 = {"name": "",
          "description" : """ """, 
          "exits" : {"west": "First" , "south":"Fifth" , "east":"Third"},
          "items" : []}

rooms = {"First" : room_1,
         "Second" : room_2,}
```

Comment: Could you please remove unnecessary empty lines in your code and also explain what is the expected result and what problems are you having right now

Comment: The import of `string` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the script you posted work, you need to:

1. Move the `for` lop to the end of the script (after you set the value
   of `rooms`). It operates on `rooms` variable, which must be defined
   firs
2. Fix the `for` loop. If you want to modify a value of a dictionary, access it with `rooms[key]`, not `rooms['value']`.

`Something like this:

```
import random
names = ['This', 'happens', 'all', 'the', 'time']

rooms = {
    "First": {},
    "Second": {},
}

for key in rooms:
    # do something with value
    name = random.choice(names)
    rooms[key]["name"] = name
    names.remove(name)
```